# How do I run a program under GDB with an environment variable set to the contents of a file?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, gdb, shellcode

How do I run gdb with environment variables set such as in the example below?

```
gdb (env -i SHELLCODE="`cat ~/shellcode.bin`" ./vulnerable)
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can use the [`set environment` command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Environment.html) before starting the program you want to debug:

```
set environment MYVAR abc
```

However, from your question it looks like you want to get the content of the environment variable from a file, and there's no way to do that from the GDB shell. You can however just start GDB with the variable already set, and it will be kept when starting the program to debug. You can verify this with the `show environment` command.

```
$ MYVAR="$(cat x.txt)" gdb ./vulnerable
```

or:

```
$ export MYVAR="$(cat x.txt)"
$ gdb ./vulnerable
```

or even using `env`:

```
$ env -i MYVAR="$(cat x.txt)" gdb ./vulnerable
```

Then:

```
(gdb) show environment MYVAR
MYVAR=...
(gdb) run
```

You might want to check that your shellcode does not contain `\x00` bytes though, as that can cause some problems (not 100% sure since I didn't test it).

Comment: `set env MYVAR=abc` sets a variable named `MYVAR=abc`. You want `set env MYVAR abc` or (equivalent) `set env MYVAR = abc` (with spaces around the `=` sign).

Comment: @EmployedRussian the GDB doc I linked states *"the spaces around '=' are used for clarity here. They are not actually needed"*. Are you saying that's not the case? I've edited that anyway.

Comment: Hmm, this must have been fixed -- I don't see a problem using GDB-10.0, but I am pretty sure this didn't work in GDB-7.x releases.